# How to follow DSC script in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dsc

Is it possible to follow execution of DSC scripts in C#? Is it possible to catch DSC configuration output in C#? 
I have a few DSC scripts and I want to follow their execution in C#.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "follow"? Capture the output? Debug? DSC files are Powershell files which means you need to create a Powershell pipeline to run them. Once you have that pipeline you already have access to the output pipes.

Comment: You could monitor the DSC event logs using WMI. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/logresource) for how to enable logs other than the Operational one.

Comment: This link has information regarding querying the status of a node and information regarding the event logs that you could monitor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/troubleshooting

Comment: I mean Capture the output